# Best way to format nest arrays in JSON?

Tags: python, json

I have a clustering algorithm that I am making into a RESTful service, that receives movies in a POST in Flask for clustering in JSON such as:

```
{"movies": ["movie1","movie2",...]}
```

I receive the clusters back from as two separate arrays to send in the POST response. The clusters of the movie names and recommendations for that cluster, as such:

Array1 of clustered movies:

```
[["movieClusterName1", "movieClusterName2",...etc],
["movieCluster2Name1", "movieCluster2Name2",...etc]]
```

Array2 of recommendations for each cluster:

```
[["movieRecCluster1", "movieRecCluster2",...etc],
["movieRecCluster2", "movieRecCluster2",...etc]]
```

What is the best way to format and return this in JSON?

Something like this maybe:

```
{

"clusters": [
        ["movieClusterName1", "movieClusterName2",...etc],
        ["movieCluster2Name1", "movieCluster2Name2",...etc]
    ],
"recommendations":  [
        ["movieRec1ForCluster1", "movieRec2ForCluster1",...etc],
        ["movieRec1ForCluster2", "movieRec2ForCluster2",...etc]
    ]

}
```

I can't imagine this being proper a JSON response for this use case. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to format JSON? Try to use `pprint` module.

Comment: To reply to the POST request with the results in Flask.

Comment: Looks fine to me. It's not great solution but not a bad one either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your goal correctly, you're looking for a good way to represent this information.

For that, you should first try to organize the response you're getting into logical groupings. Ask yourself what each item in that list represents, what do they *belong* to, so to speak.

In the case here, both the recommendations, and the movies inside a cluster, belong to the cluster itself. So, just group it that way. The clusters can be either given as a dict or as a list (of dicts, which i've realised isnt very intuitive either). My recommendation would be the first method.

```
{
    "Cluster1": {
        "Movies": ["Movie1", "Movie2"],
        "Recommendations": ["RecMovie1", "RecMovie2"]
    },
    "Cluster2": {
        "Movies": ["Movie1", "Movie2"],
        "Recommendations": ["RecMovie1", "RecMovie2"]
    }
}
```

OR

```
[{
        "Cluster1": {
            "Movies": ["Movie1", "Movie2"],
            "Recommendations": ["RecMovie1", "RecMovie2"]
        }
    },
    {
        "Cluster2": {
            "Movies": ["Movie1", "Movie2"],
            "Recommendations": ["RecMovie1", "RecMovie2"]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this clue may help you to complete your task..

```
data = {}
data['clusters'] = []
data['recommendations'] = []

print data
```

Output :-  {'cluster': [], 'recommendations': []}

## Now, you can append the values into the keys which will accept array of values like this,

```
data['clusters'].append(something)
data['recommendations'].append(something)
```